# Why doesn't bitmap data from TextureView.getBitmap update in an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, textureview

I have a piece of code that displays camera preview in a `TextureView`. Once in a while (let's say the user presses a button) I obtain a bitmap from the `TextureView` and set it for display in an `ImageView`, like this:

```
private void freezeFrame() {
  textureView.getBitmap(freezeBitmap);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(freezeBitmap);
}
```

The `freezeBitmap` is pre-allocated and reused on multiple calls to the above method.

The problem is that the `ImageView` keeps showing the state of the bitmap from the first call to `freezeFrame()`. Calling `imageView.invalidate()` doesn't help.

The problem disappears when I do **one** of the following:

- set `imageView` to use a software layer (this leads me to believe the bitmap is correctly obtained from the `textureView` but not uploaded to the GPU in hardware mode),
- create a new bitmap on each call to `getBitmap()`,
- modify the bitmap, e.g. with `freezeBitmap.setPixel(0, 0, 0)`.

So I wonder: why doesn't `ImageView` "notice" that the bitmap has been updated by `TextureView.getBitmap` yet it does notice the change performed by `setPixel()`?
Is there a good way to force the update?

Comment: Your experimental results suggest that something is maintaining a "dirty" flag. I wonder if the hardware acceleration code is attempting to avoid re-uploading the image bitmap if it hasn't changed, and `textureView.getBitmap()` isn't marking the bitmap as dirty. If that's the case, `setPixel(0,0, getPixel(0, 0))` should function as a work-around. This would be worth filing on http://b.android.com/.

Comment: @fadden yes, it seems to me this is the case. I did some digging and reported the issue to the Android Project, thanks for suggesting that.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208994